# Is it a good idea to use an additional server with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've never used Firebase (or Firestore) before and I'm considering using it for my new mobile application. And I'm wondering if using Firebase only, without any additional server is a good idea. Firestore does a lot of things I guess, like authentication, security and scalability. So I really hesitate putting an another server into Architecture. But I have a plan to do many server-side stuffs like searching for text or calculating something.

I think the answer is "it depends", but I want to hear some advices from people who have used Firebase before about this topic. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would say that even through @alexmamo has a very well thought out answer, there is really no way to present a thorough answer without understand the entire use case. Doing *server-side stuffs* and *calculating something* could mean anything and Firebase may be quite capable of both. The question really goes behind the scope of this site; it's a good question, just not a good question here. Take a peek at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to use an additional server with Google Firebase?

Firebase will help you build apps fast, without managing infrastructure. So you'll be able to focus on your app development and not on how to maintain servers. Perhaps, if you have requirments that Firebase cannot handle, which I doubt it, you can use an additional server.

> I've never used Google Firebase (or Firestore) before and I'm considering using it for my new mobile application.

If you have never used the Firebase suite, I recommend you get started by reading the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/). Before starting to use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I recommend first get more familiar with NoSQL databases.

> And I'm wondering if using Firebase only, without any additional server is a good idea.

There are many apps out there that are not using any other server than Firebase.

> Firestore does a lot of things I guess, like authentication, security and scalability.

Firestore is a scalable NoSQL cloud database that allow you to store and sync data for client- and server-side development. It does not authenticate users. For that, there is another product named [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) that I encourage you to use it.

> But I have a plan to do many server-side stuffs like searching for text or calculating something.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) you can find more details about Firestore search options. Regarding calculations, you can do pretty much everything you can do in a regular SQL database.